# net: ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME in Android Webview codes not working in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, webview

I tried the codes from the forum all of which is in Java. It was converted to Kotlin by IDE but it's not working. I've just started learning Android. Please help me with this. I've attached the converted code below. Also, I added this -

```
  val webUrl = webView.url
    if (webUrl != null) {
        shouldOverrideUrlLoading(webView,webUrl)
    }
```

inside OnCreate. Not sure if that's correct or not.
Below is the code---

```
private fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String) {
    view.loadUrl(url)
    if (url.startsWith("whatsapp://")) {
        view.stopLoading()
        try {
            val whatsappIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            whatsappIntent.type = "text/plain"
            whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp")
            whatsappIntent.putExtra(
                Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                view.url.toString() + "  - Shared from webview "
            )
            startActivity(whatsappIntent)
        } catch (ex: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            val makeShortText = "Whatsapp has not been installed"
            Toast.makeText(this, makeShortText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Expecting your quick support. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue this is the solution i found

```
class KaboekieWebsite : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var myWebView: WebView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_kaboekie_website)

        myWebView = findViewById(R.id.KaboekieWebsiteView)
        myWebView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        myWebView.settings.setSupportZoom(true)
        myWebView.settings.loadsImagesAutomatically
        myWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(Callback())
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.Kaboekie.be/")
        myWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(webView: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
                if (url.startsWith("intent://")) {
                    val intent = Intent.parseUri(url, Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)
                    if (intent != null) {
                        val fallbackUrl = intent.getStringExtra("browser_fallback_url")
                        return if (fallbackUrl != null) {
                            webView.loadUrl(fallbackUrl)
                            true
                        } else {
                            false
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (url.startsWith("tel:")){
                    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL)
                    intent.data = Uri.parse(url)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    return true
                }
                else if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
                    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                    val data = Uri.parse(
                        url + Uri.encode("subject") + "&body=" + Uri.encode(
                            "body"
                        )
                    )
                    intent.data = data
                    startActivity(intent)
                    return true
                }
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack()
            return true
        }
        // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
        // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
    }
    private class Callback : WebViewClient() {
        override fun shouldOverrideKeyEvent(view: WebView?, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).